# Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.String[]'

Tags: powershell

Im trying to get a list of users connected to a windows RAS server (Basically a list of VPN Connected users) and get their AD account properties,

The following command returns the data as follows (it returns 100+ users but I've just shown one for brevity)

```
Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics | fl
ClientIPAddress       : 1.2.3.4
UserName              : {Bob.Jones@company.com}
ConnectionDuration(s) : 696055
ConnectionType        : Vpn
```

So I wrote the following script:

```
$users = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics
foreach ($user in $users) {
$UPN = $user.username
Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $UPN }
}
```

However when running the script I get the following error:

```
Get-ADUser : Invalid type 'System.String[]'.
Parameter name: userPrincipalName
At line:7 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter {UserPrincipalName -eq $UPN }
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Can anyone help? I'm not sure what im doing wrong

Comment: The error says that `$UPN` contains an array of strings. Double-check its contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `UserName` property that `Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics` returns is an array (notice the `{}` around the value(s) in the `Format-List` output), grab only the first value:

```bsh
$users = Get-RemoteAccessConnectionStatistics
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $UPN = $user.username |Select -First 1
    Get-ADUser -Filter "UserPrincipalName -eq '$UPN'"
}
```